# \begin{comment} inside \begin{NiceTabular}

Tags: comments

I tried to inserted comment into a table and get error.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{22mm}lccccX[l,m]}[hvlines,rules/width=1pt]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors[RGB]{2}{184,204,228}{219,229,241}[respect-blocks]
  \rowcolor[RGB]{79,129,189}{1}
  \columncolor[RGB]{79,129,189}{1}
\Body
        &   &   &   &   &   &  Notes
\\      &   &   &   &   &   & 
\\      &   &   &   &   &   & 
\\      &   &   &   &   &   & ±10\% \begin{comment}\sout{{\color{red}(something)}%}}\end{comment} something2
\\      &   &   &   &   &   &  
\\      &   &   &   &   &   & 
\\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
}
\caption{Specification}
\end{table}
```

Comment: ...okay? What is your question? Based on the code snippet you provided, there's a comment character that might be the cause of your problem, not the `comment` environment.

Comment: `comment` is a verbatim-like environment, you basically cannot use it inside a command argument (in this case `\resizebox`). That having said do include a MWE.

Comment: It's possible to use an environment `{comment}` inside an environment `{NiceTabular}` (which behaves like a standard environment: it does not take its body as an argument) but not in the argument of the command `\resizebox`.

Comment: @F.Pantigny so , If I understand right , I can use in {NiceTabular} , but can't in \resizebox ?

Comment: Yes. However, many people would say that it's not recommend to use `\resizebox` to rescale a tabular: you will have inconsistent width of lines in your document.

Comment: @Werner what do you mean ?